# How to release a batch of celery backend resources without stopping/pausing producer script?

Tags: python-3.x, resources, celery, python-3.6

I was going through the celery documentations and I ran across this

> Warning Backends use resources to store and transmit results. To
>   ensure that resources are released, you must eventually call get() or
>   forget() on EVERY AsyncResult instance returned after calling a task.

My celery application is indeed using the backend to store task results in the `public.celery_taskmeta` table in Postgres and I am sure that this warning is relevant to me. I currently have a producer that queues up a bunch of tasks for my workers every X minutes and moves on and performs other stuff. The producer is a long-running script that will eventually queue up a bunch of new tasks in RabbitMQ. The workers will usually take 5-20 minutes to finish executing a task because it pulls data from Kafka, Postgres/MySQL, processes those data and inserts them into Redshift. So for example, this is what my producer is doing

```
import celery_workers
for task in task_list: # task_list can hold up to 100s of tasks
    async_result = celery_workers.delay(task)

# move on and do other stuff
```

Now my question is: how do I go back and release the backend resources by calling `async_result.get()` (as stated in the celery docs warning) without having my producer pause/wait for the workers to finish?

Using Python 3.6 and celery 4.3.0

Comment: You are better off by writing a script that will periodically clean-up the database records. In many cases you do not want to call get() or forget(). You just do delay() or apply_async() ... This is the main reason why I still use Redis as backend - because all the resources have expiry time specified, so I do not have to do any kind of cleanup.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am mis-understanding what "resources" is representing in this context. But how will an expiry time or cleaning the db records help? I thought "resources" are referring to the CPU/memory that the workers are taking up when executing a task

Comment: In the context of the (result) backend, they mean the "cost" of saving data. If you have (like we do here for an example) a cluster that executes 3-4 million tasks every day, storing all those results would soon make your result backend database (if you go for PostgreSQL for an example) enormous.

Comment: ooooh, so the documents is not talking about CPU/memory resources of my worker machines but the resources of my backend db (postgresql)? Thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: That is how I understand it. I could be wrong!

Comment: @DejanLekic thanks for explanation. Please write it as an answer you deserve it!